# Voltage regulation: I need 2x12V DC from 25V DC

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

I have this problem: i have an op amp, that is powered with +12v and -12v dc. Also, there is a ground connection at 0v.

Yet, my power source has around 25v dc and the voltage point 'in the middle' is missing.

I want to turn these 25V into 2x12V supply power. I expect a maximum current flow of 2A.

Now my question: Do you know a voltage regulator part or whatever circuit that can do this?

Comment: Search for 'rail splitter'.

Comment: Which is something like this: http://users.tpg.com.au/luce90/RailSplitter/functionality.jpg you would get 2 x 12.5 V, I would just add two diodes in series with the 25V to drop the voltage a little bit if needed.

Comment: [This question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79307/what-are-the-ways-to-make-a-dual-power-supply-from-a-single-voltage-source) is realated, but it's mostly about lower power solutions, where dedicated rail-splitter ICs are easier to find.

Comment: Thanks, a rail splitter is what I'm looking for.  And about the power requirements: maybe I'm wrong because 2A could be required between the +12v and -12v rail by the op amp but on the ground line which is mainly for slight pre-amplification and tone stack, it might be less. I think I have to measure that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There specialized ICs that do this conversion (from e.g. 24v to +/-12), providing what is called a rail Splitter or virtual ground, although really you just need a beefy enough buffer for the current you need. It may a bit more difficult finding a 2A dedicated rail splitter. Here's a typical setup using a power [op]amp.

[image]